# Google Maps and Jasny Bootstrap offcanvas

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-maps-api-3, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using [the offcanvas in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5kg9auc/4/) along with `Google Maps API` to build this html:

```
<div class="navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-left">
        <a class="navmenu-brand" href="#">mapErp</a>
        <ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Slide In</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Push</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reveal</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Off Canvas Navbar</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Slide In</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Push</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reveal</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Off Canvas Navbar</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </div>  
    <div class="canvas">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-toggle-reveal" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-recalc="false"    data-target=".navmenu" data-canvas=".canvas"> 
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">mapERP</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-pills" id="navbarCollapse">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 pull-left">
                            <form class="navbar-form" role="search" id="search-form">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="geo-search" id="geo-search">
                                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div> 
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right clearfix">
                            <li><a class="navbar-text" id="userName"style="display:none;"></a></li>
                            <li><img class="img-responsive img-circle" id="userImg"
                             src="" style="display:none;"></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="authorize-button">Login</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>          
                </div>  
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </div>
```

This is all my `css` loaded after `bootstrap` and `jasny-bootstrap` is loaded:

```
 html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#map-canvas {
    z-index:1000;
}
body {
    padding-top:60px;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
a.navbar-toggle {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.navmenu {
    z-index: 1;
}
.canvas {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0 0 0;
    background: #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 0) {
    .navbar-toggle-reveal {
        display: block;
        /* force showing the toggle */
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    body {
        padding: 0;
    }
    .navbar {
        right: auto;
        background: none;
        border: none;
    }
    .canvas {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
#map img {
    max-width: none;
}
#panel-closer {
    color:#FFF
}
#userImg {
    margin-right:10px;
}
html {
    height: 100%
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top:55px;
}
#map-canvas {
    height:100%;
}
/*hardcoded values for displaying in infowindow*/
.content {
    width:435px;
    height:319px;
}
#ma-form label {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
}
.gcontainer {
    width:36px;
}
.dropdownOptionsDiv {
    width:140px;
}
.checkboxContainer {
    width:140px;
}
```

[I find that the map loads but is not displayed](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zchkdm91bcwyxqa/Screenshot%202014-09-25%2023.04.43.png?dl=0),I believe that it is rendered below other elements, so I changed the `z-index` of `#map-canvas` using:

```
 #map-canvas{
  z-index:1000;
 }
```

For my js, assume a simple initialize function:

```
   function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);
  }
  //instead of this,I pass a callback to the api script:  
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I noticed that the `.gm-style` a child of `#map-canvas` had a `z-index:0`,so I tried to change the `z-index` to `1001` like this:

```
$(".gm-style").css("z-index","1001");
```

I also tried to move `#map-canvas` out of the `.canvas`, [it looked like this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8nvppp4xcmxko06/Screenshot%202014-09-25%2023.39.23.png?dl=0).

[Also there is the issue of rendering in Firefox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t80mxyq03zfoe0x/Screenshot%202014-09-25%2023.52.21.png?dl=0).

[I have a fiddle with the map but its not working for me](http://jsfiddle.net/vamsiampolu/aygmr578/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API adds an element inside `#map-canvas` that has `position: absolute` set. This take the map out of the document flow, and leaves `#map-canvas` with a height of `0px`.

Add a height to `#map-canvas` that isn't `100%` (unless you start from the parent elements) and the map displays.

```
#map-canvas {
  height: 200px;
}
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/tapufoterize/1

Comment: thanks for an amazing answer,the map now displays along with the sidebar but I have a few additional problems,the sidebar is partially visible below the navbar,is it because of the `body:{padding-top:60px}`

Comment: [This is what I mean by the above comment,I toggle padding top in the css for body](http://gifmaker.cc/PlayGIFAnimation.php?folder=20140926032iLCp0WTmi6wWF8beCfx5u&file=output_BMDbDK.gif)